facing an error in fetching data of the user after login-in using passport-google-Oauth
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) this is the error I am getting i have checked the Google Cloud console my auth.js, and index.js and I am using passport Google authentication for the first time as I am learning it.
this is my auth.js code which I am routing after logging in
// Route for when login is successful
router.get("/login/success", (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: "successfull",
      user: req.user,
      //   cookies: req.cookies
    });
  }
});

this is my app.JSX code where I am trying to fetch the data if the user is authenticated -->
 const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() =>{

    const getUser = () => {
      fetch("http://localhost:5173/auth/login/success", {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) return response.json();
          throw new Error("authentication has been failed!");
        })
        .then((resObject) => {
          setUser(resObject.user);
          console.log("res.obj user",user)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    };
    getUser();
  }, [])
console.log('this is user',user);

i checked all the files and tried revising the according to me code is write but i am getting user ass null, i want to fetch the user data from the google-oauth by passport js and display it on frontend client side
